# Kotlin and MockK throw com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Using Zulu JDK (8u242b20) in an Java application, I'm receiving an exception when trying to run a test from a kotlin class as follows:

```
class SomeTest {
  @MockK
  private lateinit var fileService: FileService

  @SetUp
  fun setUp(){
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
  }

  @Test
  fun `foo`(){
    // do something
  }
}
```

The exception is as follows

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.something.SomeTest.setUp(SomeTest.kt:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during attachment using: net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent$AttachmentProvider$Compound@6156496
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:384)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:358)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:326)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:312)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.JvmMockKAgentFactory.initInstrumentation(JvmMockKAgentFactory.kt:127)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.JvmMockKAgentFactory.init(JvmMockKAgentFactory.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<init>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:46)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<clinit>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:169)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.Attacher.install(Attacher.java:84)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:379)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: no providers installed
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
    ... 36 more


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway

    at com.something.SomeTest.setUp(SomeTest.kt:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

It started after using MockK, using kotlin was fine before.
Any idea what could be the cause of this?

I don't know what other details to add, everything should be visible from code, but I'm still unable to post the question due to stackoverflow restrictions, so this is just generating some random blabla text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ByteBuddy needs classes that are inside `tools.jar` library which is part of JDK and most probably missing from your classpath. You can add `$JAVA_HOME/lib` to your classpath or add the dependency with maven instead.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```